# Hyper-v is disabling my wifi network by putting as default an unidentified lan

Tags: windows, docker, networking, hyper-v

in order to make docker work on  my windows machine I had to turn on the "hyper-v" feature.
Problem is that now, after reboot, I find myself in an "unidentified network" and, in the network options, I see that the default adapter is set to an "hyper-v virtual ethernet" and my wifi adapter is disabled!
I cannot enable my wifi adapter until I disable the hyper-v ethernet (that, by the way, it is set as default).

Is there a way to delete this damn adapter? Or at least make it so that wi-fi and ehternet are still the default?

I even tried to manually set the metric but it doesn't work (I guess because wifi doesn't automatically connect at startup).
Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should enable your hyper-V again and define whether the wifi can be enable and you do the other step to turn off hyper-V. I think you must turn off some other neccesary options. If you do the following steps you can't access the network i think you should use ubuntu because it fully supports docker and is so connvenient